# swapping array rows and printing, c

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

this is something that's been bugging me for the past two hours. I'm trying to swap two rows in a two dimensional array. This is not a problem, but I want to do it with a swap function that gets pointers. Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void swapRows(int **a, char **b)
{
    int *temp = *a;
    *a = *b; // WARNING #1
    *b = temp; // WARNING #1

}

void print(int a[][2],int rows,int cols)
{
    int i,j;
    for (i=0; i<rows; i++)
    {
        for (j=0; j<rows; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int matrix[2][2] = {{1,2},{3,4}};
    print(matrix,2,2);
    swapRows(&matrix[0],&matrix[1]); //WARNING #2
    print(matrix,2,2);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

So, here are my questions:

1)The swap functions only swaps between the first elements in each array, which makes sense.  How do I get it to swap the other elements? Do I HAVE to iterate the entire row?

2)When declaring print it only worked if i set `a[][]2`. Before that I tried writing `int **arr` but I had a segmentation fault. Why is that? Also, why must I specify the number of cols in the array argument? I have rows and cols for that, why does the compiler forces me to do so?

3)finally, using this version of `print()` I get a warning from the compiler `passing argument 2 of ‘swapRows’ from incompatible pointer type` (warning #2 in the code) and I get another warning (#1) : `assignment from incompatible pointer type` in `swapRows()`. Why is that?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The second pointer type is of char, so you are not pointing to the same types, unless that is a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The source of your confusion:

The type of

```
int m1[2][2]; // a *single* block of memory of size 2*2*sizeof(int)
              //
              // this is a *real* 2d-array
```

is ***not*** the same as that of

```
int **m2;  // a pointer of size sizeof(int*) almost certainly the 
           // equal to sizeof(void*)
           //
           // This could be made to point at at least two logically 
           // distinct blocks of memory and *act* like a 2d-array
```

Yes, `m2` (pointer to a pointer) *can* be dereferenced using `[][]`, but `m1` (a actual two dimensional array) ***can not*** be dereferenced with `**`.

This means that your call to swap rows is a horrible error. Look why...

- `matrix[0]` is the first sub array (and `int[2]` containing `{1,2}`), taking the address of it is a null operation that gets the address of matrix[0][0], which is a spot in memory containing the integer representation of `1` (that is this is a pointer-to-int).
- A similar argument applies to `&matrix[1]` it points a memory containing `2`.

The you call `swapRows` which thinks that these arguments are pointers-to-pointers-to-int (which they are not, so your compiler throws a warning). It will run though because a pointer-to-int is the same size as a pointer-to-pointer-to-int (that isn't strictly guaranteed, but you'll usually get away with it). What it does when it runs is swap the point-to-int sized contents of `a` with the pointer-to-int sized contents of `b`. If it happens to be the case that `sizeof(int) == sizeof(int*)` (which is not uncommon), this will amount to swapping `matix[0][0]` with `matrix[1][0]`.

That is not what you wanted.

### What can you do about it?

- Declare `matrix` as a pointer to pointer and allocate the memory as in a ragged array, then use your existing swap
- Declare `matrix` as an array of pointers and allocate memory for the rows, then use your existing swap
- Keep the existing declaration of `matrix` and re-write the swap to swap every value.
- Keep the existing declaration of `matrix`, but also provide an accessor array of pointers, use your existing swap on the accessor, and always use the accessor (the only possible advantage of this over the first two options is that everything resides on the stack).
- Use the row-as-a-structure hack.

### Row-as-a-structure

Consider this

```
typedef struct {
   int r[2];
} row_t;
row_t m3[2];
```

`m3` is an array of structures each of which is an array of `int`s. Access is a little awkword: `m3[i].r[j]`, *but* you can do

```
row_t temp = m3[n];
m3[n] = m3[m];
m3[m] = temp;
```

to swap rows.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand. Can you give an example please? Thanks

Comment: I presume that someone told you *"in c arrays are pointer"*, right? Well, there were feeding you a line. In c arrays decay to pointers very easily and pointers addition can be represented with array notation, but they are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays and pointers are different things, although C makes them behave similarly in many cases.  You also accidentally used a char instead of an int for the second parameter.  Your swapRows function should be declared like this:

```
void swapRows(int (*a)[2], int (*b)[2])
```

You will need to swap (*a)[0] with (*b)[0] and (*a)[1] with (*b)[1].

C is converting the array into a pointer (with a warning), but that is confusing in this case.

It is just a limitation of C that arrays must have a size that is known at compile time.